# How we create admin module without using ui component in magento2

Tags: magento2, module, grid, uicomponent, adminform

As I am new to Magento2, found some difficulties with ui components, May we create admin module without using uicomponents, Share link if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

You can use module creator http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/magento2x.php

[image]

There you can define your table fields too. Installation script for sql can be done using "Need Installing Sql or php code" option.

Comment: Yes, I know I can create via module creator but when I do customization, having issues do to ui component, Can I create with uicomponent.